# Cкачал аддон на Garry's mod, и там ошибка есть: Try to use a null physic object

Tags: lua

Вот часть кода, в которой происходит ошибка(а именно во второй сверху):

```
m_missile:SetPos(ent:EyePos() + ent:EyeAngles():Up() * 150)
                    im_missile:Spawn()
                    im_missile:GetPhysicsObject():SetAngles(ent:EyeAngles())
                    im_missile:GetPhysicsObject():SetVelocity( (ent:GetEyeTrace().HitPos - ent:GetPos()))
```

.

```
im_missile:SetPos(ply:EyePos() + Vector(0,0,150))
        im_missile:Spawn()
        im_missile:GetPhysicsObject():SetAngles(Angle(-89,0,0)
        im_missile:GetPhysicsObject():SetVelocity
       (Vector(0,0,math.min(10000,max_height))
```

Пробовал указать путь к моделям - не помогло. Что делать?
Разработчик мода до сих пор не исправил.

А это уже распакованный аддон(Ошибка происходит в файле кода, который находится в папке "lua"):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ошибки приводите текстом - это правило сообщества. А у вас настолько корявые изображения, что никто даже не будет пытаться их прочесть

Comment: Спасибо за прояснение.

Comment: Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, нужно знать апи той игры, для которой этот скрипт предназначен. Я такими знаниями не располагаю, но могу предположить, что этот скрипт пытается установить позицию несуществующего объекта в своей первой строке, до того, как объект спавнится в мире (второй строкой). Попробуйте просто поменять эти строки местами.

Comment: Хотя, конечно, вряд ли я прав. У вас здесь с виду довольно простая ошибка типизации. Похоже что одна из функций в этом коде должна принимать нефизический объект, но судя из того, что вы не указали, в какой строке ошибка и по этим ужасным отступам, не несущим совершенно никакой информации, вы вряд ли вообще понимаете, что здесь происходит. Не нужно пытаться чинить вещь, если не знаете как она устроена. Ознакомьтесь сначала с апи.

Comment: Ошибка в строке с командой создания(Spawn). При попытке указать путь к модели Garry's mod выдаёт ошибку "Attempt to perform arithmetic on global "models" (a nil value)". Models - одна из папок в корне распакованного аддона(фото добавлю). Так же могу скинуть полный файл с кодом.

Comment: Насчёт API спасибо.